# Ansible - How to loop through command with items until registered variables are equal?

Tags: ansible, tail

I'm trying to find if a file has had any writes in the last 15 seconds.

```
- name: 'Check File for Writes'
  shell: tail -n 50 /path/to/some/file | sha1sum
  loop:
    - 1
    - 2
  register: file_writes
  loop_control:
    pause: 15
  until: file_writes.results[0].stdout == file_writes.results[1].stdout
```

The expected behavior is as follows:

 1.) This task would run the 'tail' command once

2.) It would then wait for 15 seconds

3.) Then run the 'tail' command again

4.) The outputs of both tail commands would be registered in 'file_writes'.results

5.) Steps 1 through 4 would be looped until the first 'tail' command's hash matches the second 'tail' commands' hash.

The actual result:  
'dict object' has no attribute results.

Comment: what the use of tail -n ? What if the no. of lines is less than 50 ? Also I think so you should use the time stamp current - 15 sec for comparison. This would be a good and simple approach. There is an ansible module `stat` this can give you the ctime of the file

Comment: @error404 - If the file is less than 50 lines, tail just returns all of the lines in the file.  The pause would just be the amount of time to wait for new writes to file before calculating the second hash for comparison.  Although, you are right that it would not need to wait for 15 seconds twice.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to put all the logic into a script

```
- shell: "hash0=$(tail -n 50 /path/to/some/file | sha1sum);
          sleep 15;
          hash1=$(tail -n 50 /path/to/some/file | sha1sum);
          while [ \"$hash0\" != \"$hash1\" ]; do
               sleep 15;
               hash0=$hash1;
               hash1=$(tail -n 50 /path/to/some/file | sha1sum);
          done;"
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to determine if the file is being written to purely with Ansible.  It seems that I am not able to retrieve the 'register' results until the task is completed.  I have tried writing 3 tasks: one for the first file hash, a pause in between, and one for the second hash.  I was hoping to make a playbook out of these three tasks and then use the 'until' function to run the playbook until the two hashes are equal, but apparently the 'until' function has not been implemented for 'includes'.