# Is it possible to check from jinja2 if a task is retried or not?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to implement a retry-in-verbose-mode logic in Ansible but I am not sure if this is possible.

Mostly I want to do something like

```
- shell:
    cmd: some-command {{ if retries '--debug' }}
  register: result
  until: result is succeeded
  retries: 3
```

Mainly the command should run without --debug first time, and if it fails, it should be run 2 more times with --debug parameter.

I know that I could use a block/rescue approach to implement the debug part but this would add a lot more complexity (real life scenario is not as simple at that example).

So, is there a jinja2 way of checking in which loop am I? I am sure that result is not defined before the task ends, so I cannot look in it.

Comment: It is possible to implement such flow-control in the script. What is the reason this should be implemented in Ansible? See [Ansible - How to loop through command with items until registered variables are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56654059/ansible-how-to-loop-through-command-with-items-until-registered-variables-are).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question

> Is there a jinja2 way of checking in which loop am I?

No. It is not. Moreover the *cmd* is evaluated when the module is initiated and can't be changed later.

It might seem that [Loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loops) with [index_var](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#tracking-progress-through-a-loop-with-index-var) could help because the task below

```
- shell:
    cmd: "some-command {{ (item > 0)|ternary('--debug', '') }}"
  register: result
  loop: "{{ range(0, 3)|list }}"
```

would run *some-command* as requested. The problem is that it is not possible to break the loop, because `until: result is succeeded` would apply to each iteration independently and not to the loop as a whole.